# QML Repeater for multiple items without a wrapping Item

Tags: qt, qml

I want to make a view that looks something like (I left off a column for brevity)

```
 __________
| text     |
|__________|
|    |headr|
|____|_____|
|text|item1|
|    |item2|
|    |     |
|text|item3|
|    |item4|
|    |item5|
|    |item6|
|____|_____|
```

and have been trying to do this with a GridLayout. The problem is that I could have potentially many rows. It just depends on my model. So, I want to be able to have a repeater that will repeat the same n elements. However, it seems to only take one component. I would love to repeat one element but that is not how the GridLayout figures out spacing. So, it seems as if this is impossible except using dynamic object creation.

My code for the actual item trying to be repeated is this

```
            Text {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                text: abbr
                color: "#545454"
            }
            VerticalRule {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
            ColumnLayout {
                Repeater {
                    model: getModel()
                    Image {}
                }
            }
            VerticalRule {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
            ColumnLayout {
                Repeater {
                    model: getModel()
                    Image {}
                }
            }
```

So, is there any way to do this easily in qml or am I kind of on my own when it comes to this kind of super specific table ish format.

Comment: I have never heard of a "wrapping Item" solution to this problem. Why is it undesirable? I posted a solution that technically is a [wrapping Item solution][1]; is it the type of solution the OP wanted to avoid?
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304778/qml-repeater-for-multiple-items/69304779#69304779

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't worked on QML for like 5 years. It was used in a desktop client that my work shelved so a lot of this context is just forgotten. Your answer does seem to recreated exactly what was desired so I put it as the answer. I don't know if you were bored one day and found my question or what :) lol

Comment: There is no simple way in QML to show tabular data with each column and row fitting the largest element. The `GridLayout` is ideal, but for data maintained in C++. the recommended solution is a `QAbstractListModel` implementation, but it is easier to have a row `count` property and cell data slots taking the row index. This pattern can be implemented 10X faster than a `QAbstractListModel` solution, but the problem is how to use a `Repeater` to populate the columns, which is what you ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* do it with the GridLayout; use multiple Repeaters, one for each column in the Gridlayout. The following snippet reproduces your text layout:

```
GridLayout {
    columns: 2

    Text {
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        text: 'text'
    }
    Rectangle {
        height: 2
        color: "black"
        Layout.row: 1
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    Text {
        Layout.column: 1
        Layout.row: 2
        text: 'header'
    }
    Rectangle {
        height: 2
        color: "black"
        Layout.row: 3
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    Repeater {
        model: list

        Text {
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.row: index + 4
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
            text: label
        }
    }
    Repeater {
        model: list

        Column {
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.row: index + 4

            Repeater {
                model: items

                Text { text: item }
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: list

        ListElement {
            label: 'text1'
            items: [
                ListElement { item: 'item1' },
                ListElement { item: 'item2' }
            ]
        }
        ListElement {
            label: 'text2'
            items: [
                ListElement { item: 'item3' },
                ListElement { item: 'item4' },
                ListElement { item: 'item5' },
                ListElement { item: 'item6' },
                ListElement { item: 'item7' }
            ]
        }
        ListElement {
            label: 'text3'
            items: [
                ListElement { item: 'item8' },
                ListElement { item: 'item9' }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of running code]

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple Items as children to a delegate Item and use JavaScript to reparent them to the GridLayout when the delegate Item is completed.

The OP requests a solution that avoids using a wrapping Item, but a wrapping Item affords the cleanest solution to this problem and supports an arbitrary number of columns. Also, I have never seen a solution using a "wrapping Item" -- this is the page that comes up whenever I search for one.

```
GridLayout {
    id: grid
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    columns: 2

    Repeater {
        model: [
            { column1: "text1", column2: ["item1","item2"] },
            { column1: "text2", column2: ["item3","item4","item5","item6","item7"] },
            { column1: "text3", column2: ["item8","item9"] },
        ]
        delegate: Item {
            objectName: "wrapping_item"

            property int rowOffset: 4

            Component.onCompleted: {
                // reparent all child elements into the grid
                while (children.length)
                    children[0].parent = grid;
            }

            Text {
                objectName: "first_child"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignTop
                Layout.column: 0
                Layout.row: index + rowOffset
                text: modelData.column1
            }
            Column {
                objectName: "second_child_containing_more_children"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
                Layout.column: 1
                Layout.row: index + rowOffset

                Repeater {
                    model: modelData.column2
                    delegate: Text { text: modelData }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // same header code as in other answer, just moved out of the way
    Text {
        text: "text"
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
    }
    Rectangle {
        height: 2
        color: "blue"
        Layout.row: 1
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    Text {
        text: "header"
        Layout.row: 2
        Layout.column: 1
    }
    Rectangle {
        height: 2
        color: "blue"
        Layout.row: 3
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of GridLayout with multiple columns from single Repeater]