# QML Repeater for adding multiple Items to GridLayout?

Tags: qml, repeater, grid-layout

How do you add multiple elements to a GridLayout using a single Repeater?

The GridLayout component ensures that rows and columns are sized to fit to the largest item in each cell, but if you want to populate it using a Repeater it seems impossible because a Repeater can only have one delegate.

There is another [SO page asking how to do it without a wrapping Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791343/qml-repeater-for-multiple-items-without-a-wrapping-item), but I've never seen a wrapping Item solution and don't know why it would not be preferable.

How would you create the following?

[image: screen capture showing data optimally aligned into rows and columns]

Here is the model data for that image:

```
model: [  // JSON model
    {
        name: "February:",
        types: [
            { name: "R-1", size: 24, color: "red" },
            { name: "O--2", size: 16, color: "orange" },
            { name: "Y---3", size: 8, color: "yellow" },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "March:",
        types: [
            { name: "G-1", size: 24, color: "green" },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "April:",
        types: [
            { name: "B-1", size: 24, color: "blue" },
            { name: "I--2", size: 16, color: "indigo" },
            { name: "V---3", size: 8, color: "violet" },
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add multiple Items as children to the Repeater's delegate Item and use JavaScript to reparent them into the GridLayout when the delegate Item is completed.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Window {
    width: 360
    height: 280
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Repeater With Multiple Items")

    function reparentChildren(source, target) {
        while (source.children.length)
            source.children[0].parent = target;
    }

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        columns: 3

        Repeater {
            Item {
                id: wrappingItem
                Component.onCompleted: reparentChildren(this, grid)

                Text {
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop|Qt.AlignRight
                    Layout.rowSpan: modelData.types.length
                    text: modelData.name
                }
                Repeater {
                    model: modelData.types

                    Item {
                        Component.onCompleted: reparentChildren(this, wrappingItem)

                        Text {
                            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop|Qt.AlignHCenter
                            text: modelData.name
                        }
                        Rectangle {
                            width: modelData.size; height: width
                            color: modelData.color
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            model: [  // JSON model
                {
                    name: "February:",
                    types: [
                        { name: "R-1", size: 24, color: "red" },
                        { name: "O--2", size: 16, color: "orange" },
                        { name: "Y---3", size: 8, color: "yellow" },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "March:",
                    types: [
                        { name: "G-1", size: 24, color: "green" },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "April:",
                    types: [
                        { name: "B-1", size: 24, color: "blue" },
                        { name: "I--2", size: 16, color: "indigo" },
                        { name: "V---3", size: 8, color: "violet" },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've searched quite a bit for how to do this and never saw this solution. Can someone point to where a wrapping Item solution has been discussed?